TypeError: _models_user_model__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default?.findOne is not a function
I'm currently developing a web application using Next.js, a framework built on top of React. As part of the authentication system for my application, I'm exploring the use of Google OAuth authentication provided by a library called Auth.js. The goal is to allow users to sign in using their Google accounts securely. Additionally, I'm planning to store user data, such as user information in a MongoDB Atlas database. However, during the implementation process, I've encountered an error. It succeded storing the user data in MongoDB atlas database but it will suddenly display this error in terminal.
[auth][error] JWTSessionError: Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#jwtsessionerror
[auth][cause]: TypeError: _models_user_model__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default?.findOne is not a function at Object.session (webpack-internal:///(middleware)/./auth.ts:27:99)
[auth][details]: {}

here's my auth.ts:
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";
import User from "@/models/user.model";
import { connectToDB } from "@/lib/database/index";

export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      // console.log("SESSION: ", session);
      // store the user id from MongoDB to session
      const sessionUser = await User?.findOne({ email: session?.user?.email });
      if (sessionUser) {
        session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();
      }
      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ profile }) {
      try {
        await connectToDB();
        // console.log("PROFILE: ", profile);
        // check if user already exists
        const userExists = await User?.findOne({ email: profile?.email });
        // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
        if (!userExists) {
          await User?.create({
            email: profile?.email,
            username: profile?.name?.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase(),
            image: profile?.picture,
          });
        }
        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking/creating user: ", error);
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
});

here's my user.model.ts:
import { Schema, model, models, Document } from "mongoose";

export interface IUser extends Document {
  email: string;
  username: string;
  image: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema<IUser>({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "Email is required!"],
  },
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required!"],
    match: [
      /^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/,
      "Username invalid, it should contain 8-20 alphanumeric letters and be unique!",
    ],
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
});

const User = models?.User || model<IUser>("User", UserSchema);

export default User;


figured it out. It seems not working due to middleware having something to do with edge runtime which is not supported. So, I just created auth.config.ts and middleware so that inside the middleware imported the auth.config.ts instead of auth.ts.
